# mysql: Can I use an Case Expression to execute other statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, case, sql-insert

```
SET @Count = '2';
SELECT CASE @Count 
WHEN 1 THEN INSERT INTO customer (First_Name) VALUES (John)  
WHEN 2 THEN INSERT INTO customer (First_Name) VALUES (Mary) 
ELSE INSERT INTO customer (First_Name) VALUES (Ray) 
END;
```

--this is a mysql case expression. Can I use it to execute other mysql statements like this? Actually want to execute a block of statements depending on the value of @count

Answer (score 1):

You can move the logic within a single statement:

```
insert into customer(firstname)
select case @Count
    when 1 then 'John'
    when 2 then 'Mary'
    else 'Ray'
end
```

Alternatively, you want [a `case` *statement*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) rather than a `case` expression:

```
case @Count
    when 1 then insert into customer(firstname) values('John');
    when 2 then insert into customer(firstname) values('Mary');
    else insert into customer(firstname) values('Ray');
end case;
```